# C# parse XML in a predefined format

Tags: c#, xml

Below is my sample xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AAA>
<BBB specName="A" delimiters="," commentChars="#" titleLines="1">
    <DDD name="SSS" col="0"/> 
    <EEE key="XXX">model</EEE> 
</BBB>
<CCC fName="Test" specName="TestRange" >Bol</CCC>
</AAA>
```

In C# how can i read this xml in the below format

```
H=filename.xml


string a = H.root["AAA"].optionset["BBB"].attribute["specName"];
string b=H.root["AAA"].optionset["BBB"].option["EEE"].attribute["key"];
string c=H.root["AAA"].optionset["BBB"].option["EEE"].value;
string d=H.root["AAA"].optionset["CCC"].value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse it and use LINQ-to-XML afterwards.

Your semi-pseudo code is actually fairly close to the end result. For this reason I have taken the liberty to provide the solution.

```
void Main()
{
    string file = "<AAA><BBB specName=\"A\" delimiters=\",\" commentChars=\"#\" titleLines=\"1\"><DDD name=\"SSS\" col=\"0\"/><EEE key=\"XXX\">model</EEE></BBB><CCC fName=\"Test\" specName=\"TestRange\">Bol</CCC></AAA>";
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(file);

    var a = doc.Element("AAA").Element("BBB").Attribute("specName").Value;
    var b = doc.Element("AAA").Element("BBB").Element("EEE").Attribute("key").Value;
    var c = doc.Element("AAA").Element("BBB").Element("EEE").Value;
    var d = doc.Element("AAA").Element("CCC").Value;    


    Console.WriteLine (a);
    Console.WriteLine (b);
    Console.WriteLine (c);
    Console.WriteLine (d);
}
```

Output:

> A
>   XXX
>   model
>   Bol